# checking to see if product is downloadable in Woo commerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display a note on single product pages of a WooCommerce store whenever the product is downloadable. I've created a function that works except for the part that checks for whether the product is downloadable. Right now the page seems to just quit rendering content when it reaches to point where this note would go. I've googled nine ways to Sunday on this and cannot seem to make it work. Any help would be appreciated--thanks. My function is below:

```
//add text note to product description page for all downloadable products
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' , 'append_download_note' 
);
function append_download_note() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->is_downloadable() ) {
        echo '<p>Please note: a link to your downloadable product will be 
        available on the purchase confirmation page.</p>';
    }
}
```

Comment: I just put this code in my local host for testing, and it works. It actually display the message if the product is downloadable. I don't know what could be wrong on your side. Any other information you could share? Error Log in your browser? Have you trying changing themes? I tried this in storefront and it works.

Comment: Did you use woocommerce templates in your theme ?

Comment: Templates? Yeah the theme i used is compatible with Woocommerce.I just pasted the code in my theme functions.php and thats all. I used storefront theme and Gon theme, it works with both themes.

Comment: Sounds like I'm looking at a theme conflict or something along those lines. The theme is Flatsome, I believe it does use templates. Let me turn PHP debugging on in my test server and see what it says. Appreciate the help--I'll report back.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to everyone here. 

I was able to get this working but only for simple products. If it's a variable product, the function doesn't do anything. 

Any ideas on how to revise this code so it works with variable products?

Comment: Odd–I’m testing, and if I substitute 

$product->is_type( ‘variable’ )” 

for 

$product->is_downloadable()

I can get it to display the text.

If I do 

$product->is_type( ‘variable’ ) && $product->is_downloadable()

it doesn’t work.

I’m really scratching my head here.

I also tried 

has_term( ‘Knitting Patterns’ )

and that didn’t work either (“Knitting Patterns” is a product category that all the downloadable products on the site share).

Any ideas here? Seems like these approaches should work…